# How rotate camera on one touch (in Unity3d, with camera Perspective)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I making viewer big model in Unity3d for mobile.
How rotate camera on one touch around self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is doc about TouchInput [Unity Doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). E.g You can count screen width and hight to angle and rotate camera object. Or You can use one of assets from Asset Store e.g : [Simple Touch Camera Script](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14489)